# compare a directory of files with an svn revision

Tags: svn, version-control

If I have a directory of files (with subdirectories) that is not under source control (no .svn directories), is there any way to compare it with a revision in svn (i.e. "svn diff")?

Similar question: if I have a directory of files that **is** under source control, can I do a diff to a different URL than the one it was checked out from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to export the revision in question to a directory next to your originals.  Then use plain old `diff -r` (the non-svn variety).

Another option is to `svn add` your originals, then use the two-URL version of `svn diff`.  But that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) for this sort of thing.